# Is there a way to filter for a message header on functional spring cloud stream binder?

Tags: java, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

In @StreamListener way (non-functional) of receiving message there was a condition like this:

```
@StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT, condition = "headers['type']=='bogey'")
```

What i'm doing right now:

`spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=process`
`spring.cloud.stream.bindings.process-in-0.destination=my-topic`

```
@Bean
public Consumer<Message<SomeDTO>> process() {

        return message -> Mono.just(message)
                .doOnNext(msg -> LOGGER.debug("Message received: {}", msg))
                .filter(this::headerFilter)
                .map(this::extractEvent)
                .filter(this::payloadAttributeFilter)
                .block(blockTimeout);
    }
```

But i'm filtering inside the method and when I pass other headers, with another payload, spring doesn't know how to deserealize this message, and brings a com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException even before process the message, because can't create "SomeDTO" like this example.

I want to find a way to filter for message header before the spring deserialize it's payload and crash.

Comment: Take a look at the spring-cloud-function docs : https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-function.html#_function_routing_and_filtering

Comment: I tried to apply the properties way of filtering, but it didn't go well, I still get to the main Consumer, even without headers in the message

Answer (score 0):

I used event rounting with functions to solve this problem: https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/31/spring-cloud-stream-event-routing

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).